# Excel vba kill only specified extension

Tags: vba, excel

I trying to kill all files with extension `xls`

```
Sub testt()
downloadF = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\*.xls"

Kill downloadF

End Sub
```

But it also kill files `.xlsx` and `.xlsm` and everything with `.xls*`

Why?

How to kill only `*.xls`?

Comment: Strange. Did a test: In my case, only `xls` files where deleted. Are you sure you don't specify `Kill "C:\FolderName\*.xls*"` ?

Comment: No. Im sure and check many time. deleting everything

Comment: I can confirm the example from FunThomas.

Comment: please put a break point on `Kill downloadF` and post here the value of `downloadF` when it reaches the break point

Comment: "C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\*.xls"

Comment: Select `downloadF`, Click `Shift + F9` to see the value of `downloadF`.

Comment: Strange... Why is it not `"C:\Users\MyName\Downloads\*.xls"`

Comment: **"When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth."** - all you files must be ending in `.xls`. maybe your file extensions are hidden and the `xlsx`/`xlsm` extension are just part of the file name but the real extension remains `xls`

Comment: here slash eleminated by stackoverflow

Comment: Just in case: Did you turn it off and on again? Do a reboot and try again (we all know how magical reboots can be).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a theory as to why this is happening, but I haven't quite proven it... in the meantime I found an alternate method to delete only the intended files is to **refer to the file's "short" (`8.3`) name**:

For example, when I first checked my (**NTFS**) drive, using the `/X` switch with `Dir` at the command prompt:

> **`t.xlsx`** has a short name of  **`TF99B~1.XLS`**

[image: dir]

...and with `Dir /x`:

[image: dir /x]

...and programmatically:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetShortPathNameA Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal lpszLongPath As String, ByVal lpszShortPath As String, ByVal cchBuffer As Long) As Long

Public Function ShortPath(ByVal fName As String) As String
    Dim fNum As Integer, strBuffer As String * 255
    fNum = FreeFile
    If Dir(fName) = "" Then
        On Error Resume Next 'Create file if it doesn't exist
        Open fName For Output As #fNum
        Close #fNum
    End If
    ShortPath = Left$(strBuffer, GetShortPathNameA(fName, strBuffer, 255))
End Function
```

As [@Pᴇʜ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737041/excel-vba-kill-only-specified-extension/50738741?noredirect=1#comment88487571_50738741) pointed out, if you strip these from the files,  eg. with:

```
fsutil 8dot3name strip c:\temp\test
```

...the `Kill` command works as expected (and does *not* kill `xlsx`).

`fsutil 8dot3name strip` : Removes the `8dot3` file names for all files that are located in the specified *`DirectoryPath`*. The `8dot3` file name is not removed for any files where the *`DirectoryPath`* combined with the file name contains more than **260 characters**.

This command lists, but does not modify the registry keys that point to the files that had `8dot3` file names **permanently removed**.

For more information about the **effects of permanently removing the 8dot3 file names from files**, see [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name#BKMK_remarks).

---

...and through the command line, for a whole folder or volume at once:

> To query for the **disable `8dot3` name behavior for a disk volume**
>   that is for a specific volume, use:
>
> ```
> fsutil 8dot3name query Volume{xyz-VolumeGUID-xyz}
> ```
>
> You can also query the `8dot3` name behavior by using the `behavior`
>   subcommand.
>
> To **remove** 8dot3 file names in the `D:\MyData` directory and all
>   subdirectories, while writing the information to the log file that is
>   specified as `mylogfile.log`, type:
>
> ```
> fsutil 8dot3name scan /l mylogfile.log /s d:\MyData
> ```

**More Info:**

- [***Fsutil 8dot3name* documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name)
- [***Fsutil* documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil)

---

## Namespaces

'<sup>***Source***: [**Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx) (Microsoft)</sup>

> All file systems follow the same general naming conventions for an individual file: a base file name and an optional extension, separated by a period. However, each file system, such as **NTFS**, **CDFS**, **exFAT**, **UDFS**, **FAT**, and **FAT32**, can have specific and differing rules about the formation of the individual components in the path to a directory or file.
>
> . . .
>
> Character count limitations can also be different and can vary depending on the file system and path name prefix format used. *This is further complicated by support for backward compatibility mechanisms.* For example, the older `MS-DOS` `FAT` file system supports a *maximum of **8 characters** for the base file name and **3 characters for the extension***, for a **total of 12 characters** including the dot separator. This is commonly known as an `8.3` file name. The Windows FAT and **NTFS** file systems are not limited to `8.3` file names, because they have long file name support, but they still support the `8.3` version of long file names.

---

### `\\?\`

**Win32 File Namespaces**

For file I/O, the `\\?\` prefix to a path string tells the Windows APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows it straight to the file system. For example, if the file system supports large paths and file names, you can exceed the `MAX_PATH` limits that are otherwise enforced by the Windows APIs. For more information about the normal maximum path limitation, see the section *Maximum Path Length Limitation*.

Because it **turns off automatic expansion of the path string**, the `\\?\` prefix also allows the use of `..` and `.` in the path names, which can be useful if you are attempting to perform operations on a file with these otherwise reserved relative path specifiers as part of the fully qualified path.

Many but not all file I/O APIs support `\\?\`; you should look at the reference topic for each API to be sure.

---

### `\\.\`

**Win32 Device Namespaces**

The `\\.\` prefix will access the **Win32 device namespace** instead of the **Win32 file namespace**. This is how access to physical disks and volumes is accomplished directly, without going through the file system, if the API supports this type of access. You can access many devices other than disks this way (using the `CreateFile` and `DefineDosDevice` functions, for example).

---

**NT Namespaces**

There are also APIs that allow the use of the NT namespace convention, but the **Windows Object Manager** makes that unnecessary in most cases. To illustrate, it is useful to browse the Windows namespaces in the system object browser using the Windows `Sysinternals` `WinObj` tool. When you run this tool, what you see is the NT namespace beginning at the root, or `\`. The subfolder called `Global??` is where the Win32 namespace resides.

---

> ## *FAT Naming Convention*
>
> <sup>**Source**: [**Overview of FAT, HPFS, and NTFS File Systems**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx) (Microsoft)</sup>
>
> FAT uses the traditional `8.3` file naming convention and all filenames must be created with the [`ASCII`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character set. The name of a file or directory can be up to eight characters long, then a period `.` separator, and ***up to a three character extension***. The name must start with either a letter or number and can contain any characters except for the following:
>
> `. " / \ [ ] : ; | = ,`
>
> If any of these characters are used, unexpected results may occur. The name cannot contain any spaces.
>
> ---
>
> ## *NTFS Naming Conventions*
>
> File and directory names can be up to 255 characters long, **including any extensions.** Names preserve case, but are not case sensitive. NTFS makes no distinction of filenames based on case. Names can contain any characters except for the following:
>
> `?  "  /  \  <  >  *  |  :`
>
> Currently, from the command line, you can only create file names of up to 253 characters.
>
> **NOTE**: *Underlying hardware limitations* may impose additional partition size limitations in any file system. Particularly, a boot partition can be only 7.8 GB in size, and there is a 2-terabyte limitation in the partition table.

---

### More Information

- MSDN : **[DeleteFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa363915.aspx)**
- MSDN : **[DeleteFileFromApp function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/mt846586.aspx)**
- MSDN : **[CheckNameLegalDOS8Dot3 function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa363807.aspx)**

Comment: Nice, you got it! That additional 8.3 filename is the reason. If you strip these from the files eg. with `fsutil 8dot3name strip c:\temp\test` the `kill` command works as expected (and does not kill `xlsx`). • Nevertheless I would never have expected such a behavior of Windows. This is not what anyone would expect in 2018 and just sucks :( it makes dealing with wildcards pretty useless in Windows.

Comment: Incidentally, the reason I included a link to documentation for `DeleteFile` is not as a fix; just the opposite.  That is the API that's called by the `Del` or `Kill` commands

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I forgot about `fsutil`, II'll quote you in the answer

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DelFiles()
    Dim fso As Object, fol As Object, f As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fol = fso.GetFolder(Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads")

    For Each f In fol.Files
        'Debug.Print f
        If fso.GetExtensionName(f) = "xls" Then Kill f
    Next f
End Sub
```

Comment: I know this works fine, but i need to understand why Kill do not work

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin this example also uses kill

Comment: @Banana Yes but it's deleting files one at a time so it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

`Kill Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\*.xls"` should kill the `.xls` only.
However, can you try the following:

1. Open any folder in Windows
2. Go to View
3. Options
4. View
5. Uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types"
6. Click OK
7. See what is going on

Comment: everithing is same. deleting all extension

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - what happens if you put a file without extension?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - what happens if you put 4 files - 2 without extension, 1 with xlsx and 1 with xlsb?

Comment: What happens if you try on a non-NTFS drive?

Answer (score 1):

I have no explanation for that, but found something strange.
I created 2 files, one  `test1.xls` and with `test2.xlsx`. I copied these files to various places:

- To `%userprofile%\downloads`
- to `%userprofile%\documents`
- to `C:\junk`
- to `U:\junk` (where U: is a network share)
- to `G:\MyDrive\MyDocs\junk` (where G: is created by Google File Stream)

For the first three cases (where the files live on `C:\`), the VBA command `dir *.xls` and also the Command-prompt `dir *.xls` listed both files, while for the "foreign" drives, only the `test1.xls` was listed. I assume that the `kill` used the same logic.

(Tested on Windows 10)

Comment: Interesting.  based on that my theory is that it's not "being a wildcard", but rather **ignoring** the more than 3 characters of the extension.  I don't know much about HD Hardware, but are your external drives FAT32 vs NTFS or vice versa?

Comment: Can't confirm this. My command prompt `dir *.xls` **always** lists both `xls` and `xlsx` no matter in which of the folders mentioned above. And in VBA `Kill "C:\temp\test\*.xls"` also killed both files (no matter which folder)! • Using German Windows 10 1709 Build 162299.431

Comment: I can confirm: on the command line, `del *.xl?` deletes `abcd.xlabcdefghijjklm` etc.  Windows 7 64bit. But it's go to be the HD specification that decides. I'm NTFS where this is happening.